# What is prime power of this equation of p?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, I think when $p^2+p+1=q^a$, where $q$ is a prime number, then $a=1$. But I can't prove it. Is it true?

Comment: Please use TeX on this site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This question is answered (affirmatively and somewhat more generally) in the following paper: Chat Yin Ho, [Projective planes with a regular collineation group and a question about powers of a prime](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869383710094), J. Algebra 154 (1993), no. 1, 141–151. The proof there uses the ring of Eisenstein integers. (The issue is available online via Open Access).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Geoff Robinson, I saw the paper and it was exactly what I wanted. Very nice

Comment: Excuse me,  is it true for p^2-p+1?

Comment: I am not sure. It may be that Ho's proof can be adapted to that case. If it does not, it may point to a counterexample.

Comment: @ Geoff Robinson thank you very much for your help and advice.

Comment: @darya $19^2 - 19 + 1 = 7^3$

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich :Oops, yes, it is already noted in Ho's paper that $18^{2}+18+1 = 7^{3}$, which amounts to the same thing!

Answer (score 24):

The equation
$$ \frac{x^k-1}{x-1}=y^m$$
is known as the Nagell-Ljunggren equation. It is conjectured that for $x\geq 2$, $y\geq 2$, $k\geq 3$, $m\geq 2$, the only solutions are
$$ \frac{3^5-1}{3-1}=11^2,\qquad \frac{7^4-1}{7-1}=20^2,\qquad \frac{18^3-1}{18-1}=7^3.$$
For $3\mid k$, the equation was solved by [Ljunggren (Norsk. Mat. Tidsskr. 25 (1943), 17-20)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206645/on-a-result-attributed-to-w-ljunggren-and-t-nagell/206830#206830). For more details see also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20070824024529/www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/%7Ebugeaud/travaux/PredaYann1.ps).

It follows that $p^2+p+1=q^a$ for *any* integers $p,q,a\geq 2$ implies $p=18$, $q=7$, $a=3$.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that Ljunggren's first part of the paper you refer to also solves the case $m = 2$ completely too. There was a recent question about this here on MO and I posted [there](http://mathoverflow.net/a/206830/26538) a scan of the paper you cite.

Comment: @knsam: Thank you, especially for the scan of Ljunggren's paper. In fact I emphasized the case $m=2$ in my earlier related post (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177952/when-is-qk-1-q-1-a-perfect-square/177958#177958), and the linked paper by Bugeaud and Mihailescu mentions other solved cases (by Nagell-Ljunggren) as well. BTW I would love to read a complete account of these results in English. Under my other MO response I linked here, it was remarked that Ribenboim's book about Catalan's conjecture discusses some cases in detail (starting with page 110), but I don't have access to this book.

Comment: One of the perks of being here at Queen's is that I have access to Prof. Paulo Ribenboim's remarkable collection of mathematical papers and books. I will see if I can access a copy of the book and post here tomorrow. :-)

Comment: Yes, actually Ho notes at the end of his paper that his Theorem A is covered by Ljunggren's work.

Comment: @knsam: Having a full copy of the book would be wonderful. Having the relevant pages on Nagell-Ljunggren only (pp.110-) would be great, too! Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Also I think if p^2+p+1=3q^a, where q and p are primes, then a=1. Is it true?

Comment: @darya: Instead of asking a new question in a comment, you probably should pose this as another question. Also, you should tell why you are interested in this specific equation.